# Delete confirmation dialog not working on the first click

Tags: javascript, jquery

On delete button click I want to show a confirmation dialog and using this easy [plugin](http://www.projectshadowlight.org/jquery-easy-confirm-dialog/). The button markup looks like

```
<button type="button" class="btn contactDeleteRow" />
```

and my JS looks like

```
$(document).on('click', '.contactDeleteRow', function() {
$('.contactDeleteRow').easyconfirm();
$("#alert").click(function() {
    // Actions to perform 
});
});
```

The confirmation dialog does not appear when I click on the button for the first time but works fine afterwards on all the clicks. Any ideas why it won't work on the first click? And how to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register the plugin **before** the click and only **once**.
What you are doing in your code is registering it **after** the click.

```
$('.contactDeleteRow').easyconfirm(); // register before click

$(document).on('click', '.contactDeleteRow', function() {
    // do something here   
});

// dont register inside a click
$("#alert").click(function() {
    // Actions to perform 
});
```

Here's a full Html example that works (put `jquery.easy-confirm-dialog.js` in the same directory as the html file):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="jquery.easy-confirm-dialog.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.contactDeleteRow').easyconfirm({ locale: { title: 'This is my title', button: ['No', 'Yes'] } });
            $(document).on('click', '.contactDeleteRow', function () {
                alert('you clicked me');
            });
        })
    </script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" class="contactDeleteRow">
        Click me
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some brackets at the end of your code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.contactDeleteRow', function () {
$('.contactDeleteRow').easyconfirm();
$("#alert").click(function () {
 // Actions to perform 
}); // <-- Missing brackets here...
```

Comment: Apologies I do have the brackets but forgot to put them above